# calling setState() will execute the function value instead of passing it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code. When pressing the button, the expected behavior is that the `AxiosInstance` is recreated and the state is updated. But in reality, the instance is recreated and then executed somewhere.

```js
function createApi(): AxiosInstance {
  const api = axios.create();
  // ...
  return api;
}

function App() {
  const [api, setApi] = React.useState<AxiosInstance>(() => createApi());
  const resetApi = () => {
    setApi(createApi());
  };

  console.log(api);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={resetApi}>Reset API</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is no error in Typescript, `setApi` has the following signature in my IDE:

```js
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AxiosInstance>>
```

Which will be evaluated to something like this:

```js
(value: AxiosInstance) => void
```

Which is exactly what I did in the first code snippet, so why does it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so apparently Typescript has lied to me, it's not as simple as that. `AxiosInstance` has the following signature:

```js
export interface AxiosInstance {
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
  (url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise;
  ...
}
```

So `AxiosInstance` is a `function`, `useState` uses `useReducer` under the hood and after digging up the ReactJS codebase, I [found out](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dfb6a403357d5ac2c0ea87aa6e5a4f947de342f8/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L643) that the dispatch function used in `useReducer` only makes a simple check if the value received is a generic function

```js
function basicStateReducer<S>(state: S, action: BasicStateAction<S>): S {
  return typeof action === 'function' ? action(state) : action;
}
```

So the dispatch mistakes `AxiosInstance` (which is itself a function) for a callback because it's a function, and executes it directly.

The fix is pretty simple, make a callback to return the instance instead of passing directly in `setState`

```js
setApi(() => createApi())
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit 64427195/calling-setstate-will-execute-the-function-value-instead-of-passing-it]